# custom route no routes match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, cucumber

During cucumber tests, I get the following error:

```
No route matches "/companies/29/update_owner"
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but im sure its something stupid.

I have the following routes:

```
company_update_owner POST   /companies/:company_id/update_owner(.:format) {:controller=>"companies", :action=>"update_owner"}
company_set_owner        /companies/:company_id/set_owner(.:format)    {:controller=>"companies", :action=>"set_owner"}
       companies GET    /companies(.:format)                          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"companies"}
                 POST   /companies(.:format)                          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"companies"}
     new_company GET    /companies/new(.:format)                      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"companies"}
    edit_company GET    /companies/:id/edit(.:format)                 {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"companies"}
         company GET    /companies/:id(.:format)                      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"companies"}
                 PUT    /companies/:id(.:format)                      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"companies"}
                 DELETE /companies/:id(.:format)                      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"companies"}
```

I have tried:

```
company_update_owner_path(:company_id => @company.id)
```

and

```
company_update_owner_path(@company)
```

update:

```
= form_for @company, :url => company_update_owner_path(:company_id => @company.id), :method => :put do |f|
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code in routes.rb:

```
resources :companies do
    match '/update_owner' => 'companies#update_owner', :as => :update_owner, :via => :post
    match '/set_owner' => 'companies#set_owner', :as => :set_owner
end
```

Comment: oops,I should have posted the whole form_for, ill update it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove the ":method=>:put"

Comment: I changed it to :method => :post, and I took out the :via => :post and your answer helped me find that thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your route is declared as a `POST` but you're doing a `PUT` in the form. Fix either the route or the form and you'll nail it.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, it was Matteo and your answers that helped me find it.

Answer (score 0):

Would leave this as a comment, but the fromatting gets jacked.
If you're not aware, you can also define those routes slightly differently, too:

```
resources :companies do
  member do
    post "update_owner"
    get "set_owner"
  end
end
```